# JavaFX: Get preview image for media

Tags: image, javafx, media, preview

I have a `MediaPlayer` with a `Media` object which are displayed in a `MediaView`. I want to create a `Button` which displays a preview shot of the media with some text. The constructor for the `Button` looks like this:

```
public Button(java.lang.String text,
  Node graphic)
```

How do I retrieve the `Node graphic` parameter from my `Media`/`MediaPlayer` object, preferably at some specified frame inside of the media file?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can just pass in a `MediaView` object and it will display the content correctly.